# How to Calculate Percentage for Profile Compltance

Tags: asp.net

I have Create Many tables For User Registration Like Naukri...
When i finished registration i have to show user the profile completance ,exactly like naukri way .how can i do it in asp.net?

Comment: I have no idea what Naukri is. Can you provide a more precise question?

Comment: Ya Sure...Suppose i have 10 tables in database....If i fill 1 table then the percentage should be (5%)..if i fill 5 table then it ill be 50%...if i fill fill all table then 100%...i have to show user the percentage of ur profile completance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is better to calculate the number fields than the tables' count, as there might be tables containing more columns than other. Then you can put "weight" for the fields, if you think that some are more important, such as email address. Then go through the fields and check if they are filled. Something like

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(EmailAddress))  
{  
completeProgres += fieldWeight;  
}  

//After you check all the fields  
progressInPercentage = (completeProgres / totalWeights) * 100;
```